# MySQL - i dont see data, but mysql says, that there are rows

Tags: mysql, transactions

I have table ip_per_nat_vlan, innodb format. When I give truncate table, table is empty.

Then I have php script, which fill data into this table.

When is this script finished without errors (simple insert statemets) situation is following:

```
select * from ip_per_nat_vlan;

Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
select count(*) from ip_per_nat_vlan;

+----------+
| count(*) |
+----------+
|        0 |
+----------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)
```

.

```
show table status;

+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| Name                             | Engine | Version | Row_format | Rows     | Avg_row_length | Data_length | Max_data_length | Index_length | Data_free  | Auto_increment | Create_time         | Update_time         | Check_time | Collation       | Checksum | Create_options | Comment |
+----------------------------------+--------+---------+------------+----------+----------------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+------------+----------------+---------------------+---------------------+------------+-----------------+----------+----------------+---------+
| ip_per_nat_vlan                  | InnoDB |      10 | Dynamic    |   141291 |            100 |    14172160 |               0 |      6832128 |   25165824 |         143563 | 2017-12-24 16:26:40 | 2018-06-13 09:01:33 | NULL       | utf8_unicode_ci |     NULL |
```

MySQL says, that there should be 14172160 rows, but I dont see any. Where could be a problem? Transactions? But I dont see any running thread and no any fault.

Thank you. D

Structure of table is:

```
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field      | Type         | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id         | int(11)      | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| ipAddress  | varchar(255) | NO   | UNI | NULL    |                |
| nat        | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| vlan       | int(11)      | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| district   | varchar(255) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| idOblasti  | int(11)      | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| type       | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
| macAddress | varchar(255) | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+------------+--------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: There sould be 141291 rows, not 14172160.

Comment: Is  select * from ip_per_nat_vlan showing rows ?

Comment: @Darius Radius please add your table structure here. Your table has primary key ?

Comment: Count() doen't count the column with NULL Value

Comment: @GursheeshSingh No, it doesnt.

Comment: @LalitTarsariya Yes, it has. I am going to edit my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are various ways to "count" rows in a table.

**The normal way. Just count them.**

```
select count(*) as table_rows from table_name ;
```

**Accuracy**: 100% accurate count at the time of the query is run.

**using the information_schema tables**

```
select  table_rows
from    information_schema.tables
where   table_schema = 'database_name'
and   table_name = 'table_name' ;
```

**Accuracy**: Only an approximation. If the table is the target of frequent inserts and deletes, the result can be way off the actual count. This can be improved by running ANALYZE TABLE more often.
**Efficiency**: Very good, it doesn't touch the table at all.

As count option is 100% accurate, your table doesn't contain any data.
Check your code and default commit option of MySQL.

Looks like you are inserting rows, but not committing them, check your index length.

Check more details here

https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/151769/mysql-difference-between-using-count-and-information-schema-tables-for-coun

Comment: It was problem with transaction.

Answer (score 0):

First thing, I am not sure how mysql run this line and produce the result

```
select count() from ip_per_nat_vlan
```

count() will return [Err] 1064.
count(*) or else a field name should be mentioned inside.

Comment: Yes, it looks, that stackoverflow remove star during copy/paste.